# Jquery textarea val() doesnt take new line

Tags: jquery, textarea

I get a textarea with a keyup function attached. When the user type something, I want this text to be rendered inside the blockquote tag. It works, but id doesn't take the newline and spaces. Can you helpe me?

```
$('#post_body').keyup(function() {    
$('blockquote').find('span').text($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *does* take a newline, however those are *usually* ignored when rendering HTML. However, you can give that `<span>` (or the `<blockquote>`) newline rendering to match by setting it's [`white-sapce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) to be the same as a `<pre>` element, like this:

```
blockquote span { white-space: pre; }​
//or..
blockquote { white-space: pre; }​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mBDjx/).

Comment: Perfect. Ultra rapid..google indexed this answer in 2 seconds!! Impressive

Comment: Oh oh. Another problem: This time blocquote text never goes in new line if I don't press "enter" key. It doesnt know that the width is over and overflowing characters remain hidden. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A raw solution would be to replace all newlines with `<br/>;` tag and all spaces with `&amp;nbsp;`