# Inserting text with new lines into a textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to insert data from a database into a textarea. I can't figure out how to make new lines though. I am using jquery's val() function to set the textarea content. I put \n but it just shows up in the textarea instead of making a newline. I have also tried \r\n with the same result.

UPDATE

Ok, I noticed if I just hardcode a string with \n in the val() function that it works. So the problem must be somewhere with the string I am returning via ajax from php. I am using $.ajax to call PHP which gets the value from mysql. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

HTML

```
<textarea id='topContent' class='divContent' rows='8'></textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$('#dialogDiv').on('submit', '#insertMacroForm', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        data: 'request=loadMacro2&id='+$('#macroSelection').val(),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#topContent').val(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM POEMACRO WHERE POEID=' . db2_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result = db2_exec($conn, $query) or die(db2_stmt_errormsg());
while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print $row['POEMACRO'];
}
?>
```

Comment: There's a good answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948779/jquery-textarea-val-doesnt-take-new-line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2159670/643500

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery textarea append newline behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159622/jquery-textarea-append-newline-behavior)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('textarea').val('line1\nline2')
```

This works fine.
You need to use `\n` in your JavaScript string.
If this string is formed in PHP on server, you may need something like `json_encode()` to format the string in JavaScript format.

Comment: The string is formed with php and returned via ajax. I just tried json_encode and now in the textarea \n shows up as \\n

Comment: Your answer led me in the right direction. I ended up adding double quotes around the string in php to make it a proper json string(without using json_encode) then I had to add $.parseJSON(msg) to my javascript.

Answer (score -3):

You need to parse through your text and convert the \n to break tags <br/> before you pass it to the textarea.

Comment: Tags are not allowed inside a `textarea` element, by HTML syntax.

Comment: Didn't know that. Seen it used extensively though. Thanks @Jukka

Comment: They aren't interpreted though, so I would be curious where you have seen it.